# Passing Variables Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable in javascript. I create a link in the following manner and everything seems to be working.

```
label.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="show_box(this);"> link</a>';
```

However when I create the link in the following way where the link would also pass an associated object I get the following error from firebug -> "missing ] after element list"

```
label.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="show_box(this,'+object+');"> link</a>';
```

Is this an acceptable way to pass an object to a function. The problem is that I am creating this link within a function. The function creates links like this based upon an object that is passed to it. Therefore I cannot have this "object" as a global scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are building the script by mashing together strings, as such you can only work with strings and `object` will be automatically stringified.

Use DOM instead.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "#"; // Have a more sensible fall back for status bar readers and middle clickers
link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' link');
link.addEventListener('click',function () { show_box(this, object); },false);
label.appendChild(link);
```

… but use a library that abstracts away the non-standard event models that some browsers have.

Comment: This sort of approach is known as [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is one popular framework to look into that abstracts non-standard event models out of browsers.

Comment: jQuery is chunky though, [here are some alternatives](http://microjs.com/#events)

Comment: Dumb question, when you say "but use a library that abstracts away the non-standard event models that some browsers have." what do you mean? Would the code you provided not work for all browsers?

Comment: `addEventListener` is standard W3C DOM. Microsoft implemented their own event model, I'm not sure which version of IE you have to start at before you see support for the standard there. There may be issues in other browsers too. Event libraries take care of all the differences for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is pass the contents of `object` to output. Since it's an object, the string representation will be something like `[object Object]`. The output HTML would look like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="show_box(this, [object Object]);">link</a>
```

which is invalid. Don't try to concatenate the object, just pass it along as another argument to the function, like `this`. Or, better yet, use jQuery:

```
<!-- somewhere in the head, or at least after the object is defined -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#thelink').click(function() { show_box(this, object); });
});
</script>

...

<a href="#" id="thelink">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your object is simple variable like numeric or string variable than it will be Ok but if you are passing html object it will not work because it will be something like below.

```
    <a href="#" onclick="show_box(this,[object HTMLDivElement]);"> link</a>
```